# Problems with package xml2 in R - connection with SSL

Tags: r, xml2

I'm trying to initialize a connection with read_xml (package xml2), but it seems to return an issue with SSL.

I tried this code:

```
sucupira = "https://sucupira.capes.gov.br/sucupira/public/consultas/coleta/producaoIntelectual/listaProducaoIntelectual.jsf"
test <- read_xml(sucupira)
```

And it returned this error:

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
 Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
```

I don't know why this is happening.

Employing httr, this works:

```
library(httr)
set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ))
GET(sucupira)
```

Comment: I know this is not much of a help but I just ran the first two lines you gave and that didn't throw an error (got a bunch of warnings though)